# How class constructor works in C++

Tags: c++

I saw an online C++ test regarding the constructor. I can figure out most of the answers but am puzzled by some in the following. Hope someone can help me out.

Here's the example.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
            A(int n = 0) : m_n(n) {
                    std::cout << 'd';
            }

            A(const A& a) : m_n(a.m_n) {
                    std::cout << 'c';
            }

    private:
            int m_n;
};

void f(const A &a1, const A &a2 = A())
{
}

int main() {
    A a(2), b;
    const A c(a), &d = c, e = b;
    b = d;
    A *p = new A(c), *q = &a;
    static_cast<void>(q);
    delete p;
    f(3);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What I don't really get is why "&d = c" doesn't output anything. Also adding another overloading constructor like A(const A *a) : m_n(a->m_n) { std::cout << 'b'; } doesn't output anything either for *q = &a. So what can I do to make it work?

Many thanks for any advice. I am very curious about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no output for these because `d` and `q` are not of type `A`, i.e. they are *not `A` objects.* `d` is a *reference* to `A` and `q` is a *pointer* to `A`. Initialising a reference and initialising or assigning a pointer does not manipulate the referred-to/pointed-to `A` object at all, hence no output.

To address your question - there is nothing to "make work," it works just as it should.

Answer (score 2):

That to be more clear I will rewrite this statement

```
const A c(a), &d = c, e = b;
```

as

```
const A c(a);

const A &d = c;
```

Here d is declared as a reference to an object of type A. It does not create a new object. It refers to an object that is already created. In this case d referes to c. In fact d is simply an alias for object c.

This code snippet

```
A *p = new A(c), *q = &a;
```

also can be rewritten for simplicity

```
A *q = &a;
```

In this statement pointer q is simply assigned by the address of a. Neither object is created. Simply q now points to already created early object a.

Answer (score 1):

`&d = c` doesn't output anything because you're not calling the constructor.

If we expand that code fragment a bit...

```
A &d = c
```

What your code is saying there is "declare `d` to be a **reference** to an object of type A, which points to `c`". Because you're creating a reference, you're not calling the constructor, `c` and `d` are the same object.

The same applies to `q`, but instead of creating a reference, you're creating a pointer and assigning it the address of an existing instance of type `A`. The constructor isn't called because you're not creating a separate object, you're linking to an existing one.